# c# driver connected to replica set floods mongodb.log with Authentication failed on arbiter

Tags: c#, mongodb, authentication

I have a .net core web app and using the connectionstring:

```
mongodb://superadmin:XXXX@production01:27017,production02:27017/?authSource=admin&minPoolSize=9000&maxPoolSize=999999&safe=true&connect=replicaset,replicaSet=XXXXX&compressors=zstd,zlib,snappy&zlibCompressionLevel=7
```

I have a primary, secondary and an arbiter. On the ARBITER server (not in connectionstring), I get the following every secs which makes my server run out of disk space. It makes sense because the arbiter doesn't hold any db.  How do I make my app to not authenticate with the arbiter?  Any idea?

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-22T02:40:00.115+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20249,   "ctx":"conn2824","msg":"Authentication failed","attr":{"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-256","principalName":"superadmin","authenticationDatabase":"admin","client":"162.xx.xx.xx:24342","result":"UserNotFound: Could not find user \"superadmin\" for db \"admin\""}}
```

Comment: Update driver to latest version.

Comment: I am using v2.11.2 which is the latest.

Comment: The log file should have much more entries and certainly does not suffer from these few `ACCESS` logs. Use [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) to keep your log folder clean.

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-2803. Perhaps you are mistaken as to the source of the auth attempts.